# Added style with typescript is not loaded

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

have little problem with my auto-create tag with style.
code is very simple, canvas is added into wrapper,class is also added to canvas,but that class didnt load my css style.
**Ts.**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BodyComponent } from './body/body.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Michal';

  private star = document.createElement("canvas");

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createElement();
    this.star.classList.add("star")
    
  }

  createElement(){
    const wrapper = document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")    
    wrapper[0].append(this.star)    
  
   }
}
```

**Css**

```
.star{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lime;
    position: relative;
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="wrapper" >  
    
    </div>
<app-body></app-body>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in screenshot bellow you can see successfully added class="star" ,but is not loaded on page, in right corner of the screenshot you can see there is no css style added.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThG0x.png)

Have any advice ?

Comment: Could you show the entire ts file? Where are you loading the css file?

Comment: @Lorenzo update for entire ts is in main ts UP now

Comment: As already answered, this happens due to Angular's view encapsulation mechanism. Why don't you add the canvas element to the `app.component.html` template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because Angular uses a style isolation mechanism.

The following code should work:

```
:host ::ng-deep .star{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lime;
  position: relative;
}
```

If you wanna know more you can check [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles).

Comment: Alternatively, view encapsulation could be deactivated for the component